Interpolation when rotating an image in python
I'm very confused and looking more for an explanation, because I can't seem to find it on the internet.
So I want to create a simple gif of an rectangle that rotates around its center in python. The rectangle consists of alternating black and white pixels.
Now If I do that with image libraries like pillow or opencv they always need to interpolate some pixels and they become grey. I attached an image where you can see this.

Now if I do the same thing in Microsoft powerpoint, it can do a rotation perfectly. Where is the difference?

That's the code I'm using:
frames = []
for i in range(15):
    angle = i * 15
    rotated_img = img.rotate(angle, resample=Image.BICUBIC, expand=True)

    # Create a new image with the grey background
    frame = background.copy()

    # Calculate the position to paste the rotated image
    rotated_w, rotated_h = rotated_img.size
    offset = ((background.size[0] - rotated_w) // 2, (background.size[1] - rotated_h) // 2)
    frame.paste(rotated_img, offset, rotated_img)

I was expecting no interpolation.

Nearest neighbor interpolation shouldn't generate grey pixels at all (if they weren't there already in the original image).

Sorry, I was playing around with the code. I was using bicubic interpolation. Nearest neighbor interpolation did change the object into a very different pattern.

If you enlarged the image before you did the rotation, you'd see the same effect.

I don't know what PowerPoint does but I guess it just stores the original image and the rotation angle. It looks like the animation was made with higher resolution than the first image. With original image+angle the result can be better adjusted to different resolutions as a rotated image which is interpolated again when zooming in.

the issue is your output resolution. it's too low. all you see is pixels. you are not seeing the forest for the trees. -- that "powerpoint" example might be using bicubic, or something else with a curve that gives a tradeoff between linear and NN.

@ChristophRackwitz In the first version of the question the code used nearest neighbor interpolation.

that would explain part of the confusion.

You're not just doing a rotation, you're also expanding the image for display.  Best that I can determine, this is the image you're starting with:

It's quite small, you need to expand it for decent viewing.  Powerpoint allows you to do that trivially, and whatever you used to display the first image does the same.
It is impossible to do rotation without interpolation, unless it's some multiple of 90 degrees.  Interpolation makes mush out of fine detail.  If you then expand that image, you see the mush in all its glory.
im1 = im.rotate(angle, expand=True, resample=Image.BICUBIC, fillcolor=bg).resize((473, 473), resample=Image.NEAREST)


If you reverse the order by expanding before rotating, you eliminate the fine detail that caused all the trouble.
im2 = im.resize((377,377), resample=Image.NEAREST).rotate(angle, expand=True, resample=Image.NEAREST, fillcolor=bg)


The people who wrote Powerpoint are professionals and know what order to use to get the best results.
One last thing, don't build up rotations by doing rotations on rotated images.  Any badness introduced by interpolation will accumulate as you do this.  Instead go back to your original image and rotate once by the accumulated angle.  Instead of rotating the image once by 15 degrees and then rotating that image by another 15 degrees, use your original and rotate it by 30 degrees.
